# Typeahead - how to code it correctly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, typeahead.js

For a website I wanted to realize a type ahead search with `typeahead.js` from twitter to gather information from a local database. For the first step I was looking for some easy code which I found on a blog [`here`](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/creating-autocomplete-functionality-with-php-and-mysql/).

My developing enviroment is a local `XAMP` stack on a Mac. I know all the basics about `AJAX` and created some good working stuff with simple `javascript`. I am new to `jQuery` and just copied the code from the blog website. I loaded down newest `jQuery` and `typeahead.js` framework and implemented it as the blog website recommends it. `jQuery` is initiated properly, but I cant control if typeahead.js is initiated properly. `Bootstrap` I left out at this step assuming that its not relevant for my test. I simply wanted to catch the `Ajax` call in PHP. But finally I have no success. This is the basic code.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <title>PHP MySQL Typeahead Autocomplete</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>'; 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/typeahead.jquery.min.js"></script>'; 

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.city').typeahead({
                name: 'city',
                remote: 'city.php?query=%QUERY'
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="content">

        <form>
            <h1>Try it yourself</h1>
            <input type="text" name="city" size="30" class="city" placeholder="Please Enter City or ZIP code">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the city.php for for simple catching the AJAX call and sending back the query.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) 
  echo json_encode(array('label' => 'success', 'value' => $_REQUEST['query'] '));
else
  echo json_encode(array('label' => 'no success', 'value' => $_REQUEST['query'] '));


?>
```

All the code should do here is showing that typeahead and AJAX works. But it doesnt. And I do not know why. 
So my questions are :

1. Is the remote key in the jQuery function properly setup ?
2. The php code uses the $_REQUEST variable, other code refer to $_GET. What is correct ?
3. With javascript I can log to the console easily on the AJAX callback with console.log(...). How do that with jQuery ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is an amalgamation of `$_POST` and `$_GET`

Comment: But as you can see from the code colourizatiion, you have a rogue `'` twice at the end of the `json_encode()` syntax. So your PHP script is probably crashing

Comment: Why was such an obvious TYPO question considered worthy of an upvote?

Comment: Sorry thats a wrong editing here in SO - not in my code. Is simplified it here. I corrected it above. Anyway I think that the php file is never called.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Okay, I did not now that